# systemd how to run service after docker.service

Tags: linux, systemd, docker

I have a service file, which executes a shell script, and the script needs to be executed after docker is started. Here is what I tried, but the script is started without waiting for the docker.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=network configuration service 
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/etc/systemd/system/
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash netset.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Is your docker.service also part of the boot up?

Comment: @ferdy yes, it's enabled, and after rebooting, `systemctl status docker.service` shows it's running.

Comment: You may want to use `Wants=docker.server"` and remove `Requires` and `After` at all.

Comment: @ferdy tried that, still didn't wait.

Comment: If both services are enabled and part of boot up process then using only `After=docker.service` should work (remove `Requires=`).

Comment: @ZhenxiaoHao can you post your solution if you figured it out?

Answer (score 22):

This is the service unit configuration file I have that runs after the docker.service is up, and is also re-run whenever docker.service is restarted:

```
[Unit]
Description=Floating IP
After=docker.service
BindsTo=docker.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/floating-ip.sh
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/floating-ip.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Documentation of the options used:

- [systemd Service unit configuration manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)
- [systemd Unit configuration manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

The script executed by this service adds an iptables SNAT rule to make Docker containers use the IP address on eth0:1 instead of the default on eth0, i.e. persisting the approach at https://serverfault.com/a/686107.